# iOS Swift draw to screen

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I am new to iOS development and need help from someone a bit more experienced than me. I searched the internet and couldn't find any working solution.

I need to draw to the screen like canvas in Android. Currently I have a `CADisplayLink` to call a function every frame. And that's working well. The problem is: How do I actually draw anything, like a rectangle, a circle or a line to the screen every frame?

This is what I have (I linked this class to the view in the storyboard):

```
class Canvas: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setLineWidth(2.0)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Double(xBall), y: Double(yBall)))
        context?.strokePath()
   }
}
```

With the following code I can actually draw a line to the screen:

```
let canvas = Canvas()
canvas.draw(CGRect())
```

The problem is, that this works exactly ONE time. When I have `canvas.draw(CGRect())` in my loop which repeats every frame, it works for the first frame (the initial values of `xBall` and `yBall`) and never again. When I print the values in the `draw` method, it gets called every frame and the variables have the correct values. But it does not draw it to the screen. I tried adding the line `setNeedsDisplay()` in the `draw` method, with similar results.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `draw` is not something you call. Stop doing that. Also, `canvas` is never _put_ on the screen so no surprise if you don't see anything. In fact, from what you've shown, you just throw it away as soon as it's created.

Comment: Try calling `canvas.setNeedsDisplay()` in your `CADisplayLink` callback. You shouldn't ever need to call `draw(rect:)` directly as UIKit does that for you when it needs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the `draw(_:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw), it says:

> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should never call this method directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the [`setNeedsDisplay()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay) or [`setNeedsDisplay(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622587-setneedsdisplay) method instead.

The common approach would be to have your view controller `viewDidLoad` method add `Canvas` view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let canvas = Canvas()
    canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(canvas)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

You don’t call `draw(_:)` yourself, but rather the OS will do so automatically. All you need to do is add it to your view hierarchy with `addSubview(_:)`. And you can then just have your `CADisplayLink` update the properties and call `setNeedsDisplay` (or, better, add `didSet` observers to those properties that calls `setNeedsDisplay` for you).

By the way, if you don’t want to add this programmatically, like shown above, you can add `Canvas` right in Interface Builder. Just drag a `UIView` onto your storyboard scene, add all of the appropriate constraints, go to the “identity” inspector, and set the base class name to be `Canvas`:

[image]

And if you mark your class as `@IBDesignable`, you can actually see your path rendered right in Interface Builder, like shown above.

---

A number of refinements:

1. If you are going to implement `draw(_:)` yourself, instead of getting a graphics context with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`, you might just `stroke` a `UIBezierPath`:

   ```
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
       let path = UIBezierPath()
       path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
       path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xBall, y: yBall))

       path.lineWidth = 2
       UIColor.green.setStroke()

       path.stroke()
   }
   ```

   Like your solution, this requires that after you update `xBall` and `yBall`, if you call `setNeedsDisplay` to have the view re-rendered with the updated path.
2. Sometimes we wouldn’t even implement `draw(_:)`. We would just add a `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer:

   ```
   @IBDesignable
   class Canvas: UIView {
       var xBall = ...
       var yBall = ...

       let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
           let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
           shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
           shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
           shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
           return shapeLayer
       }()

       override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
           configure()
       }

       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: coder)
           configure()
       }

       func configure() {
           layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

           updatePath()
       }

       func updatePath() {
           let path = UIBezierPath()
           path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xBall, y: yBall))
           shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
       }
   }
   ```

   In this sort of approach, you just update the `path` of the `shapeLayer` and the OS will render your shape layer (and its `path`) for you.